# How to connect to websocket server across devices?

Tags: python, websocket, server, client

So I'm trying to get a websocket working with the [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  Python module. The websockets docs have some simple server and client examples, and they work fine when running on the same device, but when I try to use it across devices, it won't connect. I'm new to websockets, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the echo server example from the websockets docs:

```
import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve

async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)

async def main():
    async with serve(echo, "localhost", 8765):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

and here's the client example:

```
import asyncio
from websockets.sync.client import connect

def hello():
    with connect("ws://localhost:8765") as websocket:
        websocket.send("Hello world!")
        message = websocket.recv()
        print(f"Received: {message}")

hello()
```

I looked through the websockets docs. A lot of it went over my head, but a section was talking about deploying the server to some hosting service. I want to know if it's possible just to run my computer as the server, and have other people connect over the internet without using this kind of service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I figured it out. In case anyone needs to know, the server should be:

```
import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve

async def echo(websocket):
    async for message in websocket:
        await websocket.send(message)
        print('recieved request')

async def main():
    async with serve(echo, "", 3324):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

asyncio.run(main())
```

and the client should be:

```
import asyncio
from websockets.sync.client import connect

def hello():
    with connect("ws://xxx.xxx.x.xx:3324") as websocket:
    websocket.send("Hello world!")
    message = websocket.recv()
    print(f"Received: {message}")

hello()
```

where the x's are the IP address of the host.